# How to select records with duplicate just one field and all other field in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table with duplicated records on course_id field. But id field is unique. I need to select rows that have duplicates on course_id but i want show all id that have same course_id..

example output:

```
course_id|id
-----  | -----
7      |2,3,6
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `group_concat()`:

```
select course_id, group_concat(id) as ids
from t
group by course_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: but it only showing duplicate row. how to show all row

Comment: You need to provide better/more examples of your data and expected output.  As defined right now, Gordon has given you the correct answer.

Comment: @KuntalGupta . . . Remove the `having` clause.  The question suggests that you only want rows with duplicates:  "I need to select rows that have duplicates on course_id."

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
    course_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    id VARCHAR(500)
);
insert into test (course_id, id) values (7, "1,2,3");
insert into test (course_id, id) values (7, "4,5,6");
insert into test (course_id, id) values (7, "7,8,9");
insert into test (course_id, id) values (8, "1,2,3");

select 
  t1.course_id, 
  t1.id
from
  test t1
  inner join 
    (select test.course_id from test group by course_id having count(*) > 1) t2
    on t1.course_id = t2.course_id;
```

It gives a result like this:

```
+-----------+-------+
| course_id | id    |
+-----------+-------+
|         7 | 1,2,3 |
|         7 | 4,5,6 |
|         7 | 7,8,9 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Alternatively:

```
select 
  t1.course_id, 
  group_concat(t1.id) as ids
from
  test t1
  left join 
    (select test.course_id from test group by course_id having count(*) > 1) t2
    on t1.course_id = t2.course_id
  group by t1.course_id;
```

Produces:

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| course_id | ids               |
+-----------+-------------------+
|         7 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 |
|         8 | 1,2,3             |
+-----------+-------------------+
```